Analytic way to find the sup of this sequence
I'm puzzled on how to find the sup of the sequence $a_n = n\cdot 2^n - n!$, without using tables of values and numerical calculations.
Let me explain: by plotting the sequence, or by trying some values (the sequence is good enough to allow this) I can see that sup of $a_n$ exists and it's actually the max, and it occurs at $n = 4$ and at $n = 5$, where indeed $a_4 = a_5 = 40$. But I wanted to derive it in some analytical good way if possible.
Pretending to know nothing, I started by asking if the series is increasing or decreasing. Hence I tried to see if $a_{n+1} - a_n > 0$, and this lead me to
\begin{split}
a_{n+1} - a_n & = (n+1)\cdot 2^{n+1} - (n+1)! - n\cdot 2^n + n! \\\\
& = n\cdot 2^{n+1} + 2^{n+1} - (n+1)! - n\cdot 2^n + n! \\\\
& = (2+n)\cdot 2^n - n\cdot n!
\end{split}
Now if $a_{n+1} - a_n > 0$ means $(2+n)\cdot 2^n - n\cdot n! > 0$ that is $n\cdot n! < (2+n)\cdot 2^n$.
At this point I'm forced again to use the trial method. Indeed this inequality is false for $n = 0$, though it's true for $n = 1, 2, 3$ and again false for $n = 4$ and hopefully for $n \geq 4$.
I tried to think about some upper bounds but I didn't find nothing. I mean it's a mixed situation: $2+n > n$ for every natural $n$, but $2^n < n!$ for every $n \geq 4$.
Any help? Thank you!

The only analysis that I can conjure is that it is obvious that for $~n \geq 10,~$ that the sequence is decreasing.

So I'm not totally sure what you're looking for when you say "derive it in some analytical good way if possible." You can prove via induction that $(2+n)2^n\leq n\cdot n!$ for $n\geq 4$ using the fact that $2^n\leq n!$ is true for $n\geq 4$ and the result would follow.
Some other ideas to pursue if you want to solve it purely using real analysis, although after toying with these methods for an hour I couldn't find a "nice" way (i.e. without numerical calculations and they may not be fruitful):

Investigate the maximum of the function $g(x)=x2^x-\Gamma(x+1)$ for $x>0$. Unfortunately, the Gamma function does not have a nice closed form derivative so will require some numerical calculation as far as I can tell. I managed to reduce the maximum to satisfy the equality $$1+\ln(2)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}(t/2)^x\ln(t)dt$$but this does not have a nice analytical solution.
You could use the Binomial theorem to write your last inequality as $$\left(\frac{2}{n}+1\right)\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!(n-k)!}<1$$

